# @media query looks OK but doesn't work

Tags: html, css, ipad

Did a simple test of @media queries to see what works:
http://www.casedasole.it/km2014/test.html

In test.css there's a @media query that should - if I've understood media queries - change the background color from black to red on landscape tablets (1024x768). The css validates, the xhtml validates, but the background stays black in FF using Chris Pederick's Web Developer Extension -> View Responsive Layouts, and in transmog.net iPad emulator (I have no iPad).

If somebody can explain why it's not working, I'm sure I'll have fun with media queries.

Comment: You have <?xml version="1.0" ?> in the start of the document. This probably messes things up. You should remove it. Also, consider putting the HTML5 doctype instead.

Comment: I removed it, tested it again, but nothing changed. The document declaration is <?xml version="1.0" ?> because that's what I've seen indicated as necessary for websites for mobiles.

Comment: You have two declarations by the way, none of which is the HTML5 doctype. I believe the HTML5 doctype is the way to go for mobile websites.

Comment: I agree with @codingstill. Use `<!DOCTYPE html>` as your doctype in addition to my answer and you should be set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all, these are the BEST breakpoints

```
 @media (min-width:320px) { /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ }
 @media (min-width:481px) { /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or        @ 640 wide. */ }
 @media (min-width:641px) { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */ }
 @media (min-width:961px) { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ }
 @media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ }
 @media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ }
```

Now in your case, use this media query instead

```
 @media (max-width:1024px)  {
html, body { 
    background-color: #f00;
    color:#000;
     }
}
```

Comment: ah, yes. Using "@media (max-width:1024px)" instead of "@media screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" changed everything. First thing I noticed was the background changed to red in every Responsive Layout from Mobile portrait (320x480) to Tablet landscape (1024x768). That's when it clicked - what I was testing was changing styles for tablets with 1024 px width. So, using a red background as an example, what I should have used was "@media (min-width:1024px)", which changes the background to red only at 1024px. It works.

Comment: I think you need a `;` after `color: #000` (making `color: #000;`)

Comment: @plugincontainer You can also combine it to be more specific like so `@media (min-width:1000px) and (max-width: 1024px) {}`. This means the css will only be effective when the size is within 1000px and 1024px. This enables your media query to be extra specific and extra targeted

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your media query, using `max-device-width` is not valid, you can use `max-width` instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: #000;
            font-family: verdana,arial,geneva,helvetica,sans-serif;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
        }
        /* iPad and other tablets (landscape) */
        @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
            html, body {
                background-color: #f00;
                color: #000;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Why is background not red in iPad landscape 1024px??</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Please see answer to Vim Bonsu above.

Answer (score 0):

Also it seems to work if you use "@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px)"